# VBA Returns Error after Range.Find finds nothing

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets in Excel, New Sheet and Old Sheet.  I am trying to search in Column A of Old Sheet if the column contains each of the entries of Column A of New Sheet.  I am using the following VBA code to search, but it returns an error on the second search (the non column header search).  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong - any help is appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim searchrng As Range
Dim searchval As String

lastRow = Sheets("New One").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Old One").Activate
Set searchrng = Sheets("Old One").Range("A1:A10000")


For i = 1 To lastRow

    Sheets("New One").Activate
    searchval = Sheets("New One").Cells(i, 1).Value

    Set rng = searchrng.Find(searchval)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Found " & searchval & " in " & rng.Address
    Else
        Sheets("New One").Activate
        Sheets("New One").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The error is always Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Find' of object 'Range' failed.

Comment: remove this line `Sheets("New One").Activate` in both places and see if it works. See [Avoid Select](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=excel%20vba%20avoid%20select) for more information. In short, work directly with the objects instead of using `Activate` unless you absolutely need to (this is rare).

Comment: It didn't work.  I should add that the column headings are the same for Columns A on both of the worksheets - and it successfully finds the column heading.  Then Column A, Row 2 is in "New One", but not "Old One" and it kicks back the error.

Comment: you can also use `Conditional Formatting` to find the values not found in Sheet2 and remove VBA altogether. ... I ran the code and it worked great for me.

Comment: What conditional formatting formula would I use? And aghhhh I have no idea why this code isn't working for me.

Comment: What error is it giving you, and at what line?

Comment: `=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Old One'!A:A,1,0))` for conditional format on cells in column A of `New One` tab.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `.Select`

```
Sub Sample()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim searchrng As Range
Dim searchval As String
Dim oldWS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet
Set oldWS = Worksheets("Old One")
Set newWS = Worksheets("New One")

lastRow = newWS.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

Set searchrng = oldWS.Range("A1:A10000")


For i = 1 To lastRow

    searchval = newWS.Cells(i, 1).Value

    Set rng = searchrng.Find(searchval)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Found " & searchval & " in " & rng.Address
    Else
        newWS.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Does that work for you? I tested it in mine and it worked.  Make sure the ranges you give are correct.

But, I agree with @ScottHoltzman - you can do this with Conditional Formatting, avoiding the use of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help.

I was able to get it to work by conditional formatting, thanks to Scott Holtzman for the idea.  In the end, I used COUNTIF however, instead of IsError.

```
=COUNTIF('Old One'!$A:$A, 'New One'!$A1)=1
```

applied to Column A in 'New One' Worksheet.